# Error with EntityExpr code

Tags: jakarta-ee

I have a problem with this code:

```
String issueid = "10001";

EntityExpr issueExpr = new EntityExpr("issueid", EntityOperator.EQUALS, issueid);
```

When I run a code it does not load anything from database. In database issueid field is desimal(18.0) so does this causes the error because I my variable issueid is string?

Answer (score 0):

I found this from StackTrace:

```
org.ofbiz.core.entity.GenericModelException: Field with name issueid not found in the Worklog Entity
```

So I fixed code like this and now it working:

```
EntityExpr issueExpr = new EntityExpr("issue",
            EntityOperator.EQUALS, issueid);
```